# Compiling latex directly from R

Tags: xetex, compiling, r, scripts

I want to find a programmatic way of converting a `.tex` latex document to pdf.

What I usually do, and this works in most cases, is to use:

```
tools::texi2dvi(latexfile, pdf = TRUE, clean = TRUE)
```

However, I now need to work with documents that contain Asian fonts (Chinese, Japanese and Korean).  Searching on [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21046/change-xetex-fonts-automatically-depending-on-unicode-blocks/21051#21051) leads to advice to incude the following lines in the tex file:

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{MS Mincho} % for \rmfamily
```

This means I need to use `xelatex` to build the pdf.  I have tried variations on the following theme, none of which work.

```
shell(cmd="xelatex latexfile", mustWork=TRUE, translate=TRUE)
```

**Question:** How can I call `xelatex` programmatically?

**Additional information:**

- I am on Windows 7, R2.13-1
- `xelatex` is installed on my machine and works fine if I call it any other way (including via the command line)
- I am using StatET in Eclipse

Comment: but what happens when you run that shell() expression? what is the error?

Comment: If you are using MiKTeX, its texi2dvi executable has a `--engine=ENGINE` option. So you could call it directly through `shell`

Comment: I notice that this question was migrated from StackOverflow to tex.stackexchange.  This makes no sense at all - my question is not a latex question, but an R programming question.

Comment: I agree, but you should have asked it accurately in the first place . . . it's about control over spawning commands to the system from R (possibly via a 3rd party) on windows :)

Comment: @mdsumner Yes, it could have been more accurate.  And I would have made it more accurate if I understood more about the problem.  Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: did you manage to do it? I would like to know how you do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some help from the helpful people at StackOverflow, two things emerged:

1. The correct way to call `xelatex` using a shell script from R is to remove the path from the full filename.
2. The reason that `xelatex` doesn't return control is because it enters interactive mode when detecting an error.  To fix this, use the argument `--mode=batchmode`:

   ```
   shell(cmd=paste("xelatex --mode=batchmode", basename(latexfile)), 
        mustWork=TRUE, intern=TRUE, translate=TRUE)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try `texi2dvi` with an environment variable`LATEX=xelatex` (not tested).

See the source code of `tools::texi2dvi` (lines 145-147):

```
...
latex <- if (pdf) 
    Sys.getenv("PDFLATEX", "pdflatex")
else Sys.getenv("LATEX", "latex")
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I eventually ended up with the following solution:

```
install.packages("tinytex")   
require("tinytex")}
install_tinytex(force = TRUE)
tlmgr_install('montserrat') 
xelatex('Report.tex')
```

This code install [TinyTex](http://yihui.name/tinytex/), then it installs the font package *montserrat* with *tlmgr_install* function.