# How do I combine fonts for different scripts?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, cjk

I want to combine [Helvetica World](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/linotype/helvetica_world_com_complete_pack/) (for roman, cyrillic, greek and arabic) and [Hei Std](http://www.fonts.com/font/dynacomware/dfp-hei-simplified-chinese?isRatingExpanded=False) (for simplified chinese) in one document with LuaLaTeX. Hei Std probably hasn't all the glyphs from Helvetica World and Helvetica World certainly hasn't all characters from Hei Std.

Can I get LuaLaTeX to automatically choose the right font based on the input, i.e. can I combine fonts into one "virtual font"? I don't want to switch the fonts manually.

Out of curiosity I'm also interested in a solution for XeLaTeX, but I *need* one for LuaLaTeX.

Comment: In theory: yes - LuaTeX has on-the-fly-virtual-fonts. I am also interested in how to do that with `luaotfload` :)

Comment: @PatrickGundlach: I've edited the question to also ask for XeTeX-based solutions. AFAIK XeTeX also has provisions for this.

Comment: the package `unicode-math` can handle different fonts for a defined range of characters. For a text font it maybe possible in the same way

Comment: For XeLaTeX the best is probably to use `xeCJK` (see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21046/). This uses `\XeTeXinterchartoks`. For luatex there has been some discussion to implement something similar (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21625/) but the code suggested there by Taco has some problems (see the comment of Manual). I don't know if someone created something better (or is working on it).

Comment: @Herbert: this works for `unicode-math` because in math each symbol specify its font, in text mode it is entirely a different matter. ConTeXt support script and range-based font fallbacks without even using virtual fonts, so it is certainly possible...

Comment: It seems both `xeCJK` and `luatexja` are not widely heared by people out of China/Japan, although they are quite useful and somewhat stable now. I myself didn't notice `luatexja` until early this year.

Comment: @LeoLiu: It seems all the documentation for `luatexja` is in Japananese...

Comment: @Martin: http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/luatex/generic/luatexja/doc/luatexja-en.pdf

Comment: @LeoLiu: Ah. `texdoc luatexja` defaults to `ltjclasses.pdf`.

Comment: @Martin: Use `texdoc -l luatexja`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for XeLaTeX, you should use our `xeCJK` package. For Chinese typesetting in `xeCJK`, see [my previous answers tagged `cjk`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:2674%20%5Bcjk%5D).

A simple example:

```
% UTF-8 encoding, compile with XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setCJKmainfont{Microsoft YaHei}

\begin{document}
Arial font and 微软雅黑
\end{document}
```

---

And for LuaLaTeX, you can use `luatexja-fontspec` package from [`luatexja` bundle](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/luatexja). `luatexja` is originally designed for Japanese, but also useful for Chinese (due to Ma Qiyuan's work).

A simple example, very similar to `xeCJK`:

```
% UTF-8 encoding, compile with LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmainjfont{Microsoft YaHei}

\begin{document}
Arial font and 微软雅黑
\end{document}
```

The English document of `luatexja`:
http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/luatex/generic/luatexja/doc/luatexja-en.pdf

In [`ctex` bundle](http://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/), we shall also support `luatexja` as one of the background package. The new version has not been released.

Comment: Seems nice. It would be much more useful with a bit of english documentation... `:-)` Maybe an article in TUGboat?

Comment: @Martin: `luatexja` does have English document (and also in Japanese and Chinese). `xeCJK` 2.x used to have a document both in Chinese and English, but I'm sorry we updated the new version (3.x) and the English document is not ready yet. Sorry.

Comment: I'm still interested in a solution with `luatexja`.