# Japanese Characters W/O Environment

Tags: cjk

Is it possible to write Japanese Characters without environment?
LaTeX is very popular in Japan, so I don't believe that Japanese always use environments for writing on their native language.

Comment: Please see: [Change XeTeX fonts automatically depending on Unicode blocks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21046/change-xetex-fonts-automatically-depending-on-unicode-blocks) for typesetting CJK characters without special environments using Xe(La)TeX.

Comment: There is pTeX (with pLaTeX) that was specially developed for Japanese, so this is what the Japanese generally use. It has been recently supplemented by UpTeX, that supports Unicode fonts.

Comment: Phew! I was just about to submit a question for this, but luckily it popped up after I wrote about 99%.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `xelatex` ([documentation](http://xml.web.cern.ch/XML/lgc2/xetexmain.pdf))
or `uplatex` ([documentation](http://homepage3.nifty.com/ttk/comp/tex/uptex.html))

both can handle OpenType fonts. for `uplatex` you have to run the sequence  `uplatex->dvipdfmx`

an example with `uplatex`

[image]