# Is it possible to switch languages automatically without tags, in Polyglossia?

Tags: fonts, xetex, languages, polyglossia

I want to type text that may contain both Devanagari or Roman script, and I don't want to change language mid sentence every time. Is it possible to merge two fonts, one which supports Devanagari glyphs, and one which supports Roman glyphs into one language?

Currently, I am doing

```
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari-Regular}
```

And since `NotoSansDevangari-Regular` does not have glyphs for roman characters, it renders the line

`The ending हल् letter of  an उपदेश is called 'इत्'.`

as

`��� ������ हल् ������ �� �� उपदेश �� ������ 'इत्'.`

Is it possible to somehow add `NotoSans-Regular` alongwith `NotoSansDevanagari-Regular` in the language so that it can render both scripts properly without having to explicitly do `\begin{english}\end{english}` ?

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to do this with `babel`.  This new preamble should work with your document, so long as you used `\textenglish` and `\begin{sanskrit}` instead of `\devanagarifont`.  It requires luahbtex (lualatex in TeX Live 2020 works), but has a bug with xetex (as of July 2020).

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{iftex} % For \ifluahbtex, \ifxetex, etc.
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % Format the MWR for TeX.SX
\pagestyle{empty}

\ifluahbtex
  \usepackage[bidi=basic,main=english]{babel}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{ Renderer=HarfBuzz,
                        Scale=MatchLowercase,
                        Ligatures=TeX }
  \usepackage{microtype}
\else
  % The only other engine that works, as of 2020, is XeTeX.
  \usepackage[bidi=default,main=english]{babel}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase,
                        Ligatures=TeX }
\fi

\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{sanskrit-devanagari}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common, Scale=1.0,Language=Default]{Noto Serif}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common,Language=Default]{Noto Sans}
\babelfont[sanskrit-devanagari]{rm}
          {Noto Serif Devanagari}
\babelfont[sanskrit-devanagari]{sf}
          [Language=Default]{Noto Sans Devanagari}
\babelfont{tt}
          [Language=Default]{Noto Sans Devanagari UI}

\babeltags{sanskrit=sanskrit-devanagari} % Add \textsanskrit, \begin{sanskrit}
\babeltags{english=english} % Add \textenglish, \begin{englisn}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
The ending हल्  letter of  an उपदेश is called `इत्'.
\end{document}
```

[image: Noto Sans font sample]

Recall that quotes in TeX are

```
`foo ``bar" baz' or ‘foo “bar” baz’
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work. Some of the errors from the log file are:
`*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "script-not-exist"
* 
* Font 'Noto Sans Devanagari UI' does not contain script 'Latin'.
*************************************************
`
and
`Could not resolve font "Noto Sans Devanagari UI/I" (it probably doesn't
. exist).
`
This one now renders only the English words and boxes for Devanagari script.

Comment: @Hrishikesh You need to download the [Noto fonts.](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) You can ignore the warning about Noto Sans Devanagari UI or even comment those lines our.

Comment: I have noto fonts installed. They are located in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto`It contains these files `NotoSansDevanagari-Bold.ttf`, `NotoSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf`,  `NotoSansDevanagariUI-Bold.ttf`, `NotoSansDevanagariUI-Regular.ttf` as well as similar for many other languages

Comment: Can `luaotfload-tool` find them? If not, rebuilding your cache might help. You can also comment out the pair of lines declaring the `rm` and `tt` fonts in this MWE. It works for me with lualatex in TeX Live 2020, but any previous version would require luahbtex.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using XeLaTeX.
If so, as @kongo09 mentions in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21046/change-xetex-fonts-automatically-depending-on-unicode-blocks), a package called `ucharclasses` works. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[xelatex]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\defaultfont}{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\latinfont}{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\devanagarifont}{NotoSansDevanagari-Regular}

\usepackage[Latin, Devanagari]{ucharclasses}
\setDefaultTransitions{\defaultfont}{}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\latinfont}{}
\setTransitionTo{Devanagari}{\devanagarifont}

\begin{document}

The ending हल् letter of an उपदेश is called 'इत्'.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I’ve found the package to be buggy in TeX Live 2020.

Comment: It also does not work in LuaHBTeX.

Comment: I have tested with my XeLaTeX 2017 and it worked. @Davisor Thank you very much for your information that it is buggy in TeX Live 2020, I did not know that! :)

Comment: Another more serious bug in this solution is that it always switches back to `\defaultfont`, and not the font you had selected before. You can fix this by opening with a `\begingroup\devanagarifont` and closing with an `\endgroup`.