# Is there a LuaTeX analogue to XeTeXinterchartoks?

Tags: xetex, luatex

Just as the title of the questions says, is there an LuaTeX analogue to XeTeXinterchartoks?

Comment: I don't know XeTeX, can you tell us what XeTeXinterchartoks are?

Comment: @Patrick, see [xetex-referece](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/xetexref/XeTeX-reference.pdf) (page 14). It allows you to do stuff like [changing fonts of hyphenation rules for different languages without explicitly declaring them](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6361/xetex-change-font-usage-when-meeting-greek-characters-sabon-linotype-sabon-gr/21101#21101)

Comment: LuaTeX has more powerful mechanisms, so better ask about what you want to achieve.

Comment: A replacement for XeTeXinterchartoks & co could be implemented using the token_filter callback that is available in luatex. The fact that nobody has done so yet indicates to me that most people have indeed switched to other mechanisms available in luatex, as Khaled mentions.

Comment: @Khaled, I opened a new question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21625/in-luatex-is-it-possible-to-change-font-language-according-to-the-script-glyphs-u)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope so, but the answer is no.

[We](http://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/) use `\XeTeXinterchartoks` mechanism heavily to implement `zhspacing` and `xeCJK` packages to support auto font switching and other features or CJK. But we cannot transplant them to LuaTeX.

Now the same feature in LuaTeX ([zhfonts](https://github.com/liyanrui/zhfonts) module of ConTeXt) uses a totally different mechanism to implement: `\definefontfallback` and `pre_linebreak_filter` etc. If you want to do similar things in Greek, I hope it would help.

Comment: I'd say the answer is incorrect, because LuaTeX does have mechanisms that are much more powerful then `\XeTeXinterchartoks` (you already give the answer), but does not have a built-in TeX interface. But in the strict sense, you are right, of course.

Comment: @Patrick: What I want to say is that, the concept and the interface in LuaTeX is quite different. LuaTeX may do what XeTeX do, but not in the same way.