# Defining different scripts with fontspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, polyglossia

My actual problem: I want to typeset Tigrinya text, which is using Ethiopic (Ge'ez) script. But the text also contains numbers (which are afaik. in the latin script).

So I've defined a new font family using `\newfontfamily{\ethiopicfont}[Script=Ethiopic]{Droid Sans Ethiopic}` and introduced a new environment for Tigrinya using: `\newenvironment{Tigrinya}{\ethiopicfont}{}`. But the Droid Sans Ethiopic font only contains the Ethiopic script.

How do I define a fontfamily using different scripts from different fonts/files. (I guess this procedure is called patching a font?)

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{tigrinya}

\newfontfamily{\ethiopicfont}[Script=Latin, Scale=1]{Droid Sans}
\newfontfamily{\ethiopicfont}[Script=Ethiopic, Scale=1]{Droid Sans Ethiopic}

\newenvironment{Tigrinya}{\ethiopicfont}{}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section}

\begin{Tigrinya}
13 እንሆ ኸኣ በታ መዓልቲ እቲኣ ኽልተ ኻባታቶም ካብ የሩሳሌም ስሳ እስታድዮስ ዝምርሓቓ ኤማሁስ ናብ እትብሃል ዓዲ ይኸዱ ነበሩ።
\end{Tigrinya}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The [ucharclasses](http://ctan.org/pkg/ucharclasses) package might help (XeTeX).

Comment: Thanks for this hint. It looks quite promising but I still didn't manage to use `\setTransitionFrom` or `\setTransitions` nor I could find out which block to use with `\setTransitionTo` for numbers `\setTransitionTo{CuneiformNumbersandPunctuation}{\mainfont}` doesn't seam to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loading a non existent language is useless. Just add a font family for Ethiopic characters (I used Kefa, use whatever you like).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[Latin,Ethiopic]{ucharclasses}

\setmainlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily{\tigrinyafont}[Script=Ethiopic, Scale=1]{Kefa}

\newenvironment{tigrinya}
  {\tigrinyafont}
  {}

\setTransitionTo{Ethiopic}{\begin{tigrinya}}
\setTransitionFrom{Ethiopic}{\end{tigrinya}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section}

\begin{tigrinya}
13 እንሆ ኸኣ በታ መዓልቲ እቲኣ ኽልተ ኻባታቶም ካብ የሩሳሌም ስሳ እስታድዮስ ዝምርሓቓ ኤማሁስ ናብ እትብሃል ዓዲ ይኸዱ ነበሩ።
\end{tigrinya}

Text in English with ኻባታቶም ካብ

Whatever follows

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Version 2

After reading a recommendation/comment by [Khaled Hosny](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/729/khaled-hosny) I've changed the core of the snippet, so it's switching font only when needed. There is no font change on purpose if a character is a space. In the previous version, it wrapped every single character (not recommended in general as it breaks up ligatures, kerning pairs and probably other character relations in some fonts/languages).

If you can, please, use [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236996/48028) to this question (based on the [XeTeX](https://tug.org/xetex/) engine) with the help of [ucharclasses](http://ctan.org/pkg/ucharclasses) package.

In case, you would like to use serious and similar approach in [LuaTeX](http://www.luatex.org/), I recommend [Taco Hoekwater](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89/taco-hoekwater)'s answer mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21691/48028).

Still, I wanted to present an alternative to the mentioned mainstream solution by manipulation of a TeX parameter at the character level in Lua (`unicode.utf8.*`).

I've found and downloaded mentioned Droid family fonts from this [location](https://github.com/jenskutilek/free-fonts/tree/master/Droid) to my working directory ([Droid Sans](https://github.com/jenskutilek/free-fonts/tree/master/Droid/Droid%20Sans/TTF) and [Droid Sans Ethiopic](https://github.com/jenskutilek/free-fonts/tree/master/Droid/Droid%20Sans%20Ethiopic/TTF), regular versions).

The Lua snippet checks out the previous and current character and decides if there is a need for font change. I set up Ethiopic range from 1200(hex) to 137F(hex) according to this [Unicode chart](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1200.pdf).

Next to the TeX document, the snippet writes information also to the terminal for easy checking, in this example that is:

```
\droidsans{}0 123 abc 456 789 \droidsansethiopic{}እንሆ ኸኣ በታ መዓልቲ እቲኣ ኽልተ ኻባታቶም ካብ የሩሳሌም ስሳ እስታድዮስ ዝምርሓቓ ኤማሁስ ናብ እትብሃል ዓዲ ይኸዱ ነበሩ።
```

The changes of fonts are done within a group, so we return to the Latin Modern family after processing that command. We run `lualatex mal-droid.tex`. I enclose the code (I've added `abc` next to digits to see if it works with letters as should be) and a preview of the result.

The `mal-droid.tex` file:

```
% lualatex mal-droid.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty} % without a page number
\usepackage{polyglossia} % handling languages
\setmainlanguage{english} % setting up a main language
\usepackage{xcolor} % support for colors
\usepackage{luatextra} % loading luacode, fontspec etc.

% http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1200.pdf
% I downloaded fonts from https://github.com/jenskutilek/free-fonts/tree/master/Droid.
\newfontfamily{\droidsansethiopic}[Script=Ethiopic, Color=red, ExternalLocation=./]{DroidSansEthiopic-Regular.ttf} % font for Ethiopic
\newfontfamily{\droidsans}[Script=Latin, Color=green, ExternalLocation=./]{DroidSans.ttf} % font for Latin inside Ethiopic

\begin{luacode*}
function changeme()
text=tex.toks[0]
previous=nil
for i=1,unicode.utf8.len(text) do -- glyph by glyph operation
   char=unicode.utf8.sub(text,i,i) -- this glyph is processed right now
   typeit="" -- text to be typeset/displayed, initializing to be sure that string is empty
   if char>=unicode.utf8.char( tonumber("1200",16) ) and char<=unicode.utf8.char( tonumber("137F",16) ) then droid=1 else droid=0 end -- Is there a character in Ethiopic, or not?
   if char==" " then droid=previous end -- don't change a font if character is a space
   if (not previous or previous==1) and droid==0 then -- unused font or a switch, Latin
      typeit="\\droidsans{}" -- core
      end -- if, for Latin
   if (not previous or previous==0) and droid==1 then -- unused font or a switch, Ethiopic
      typeit="\\droidsansethiopic{}" -- core
      end -- if, for Ethiopic
   typeit=typeit..char -- a change in font + processed character
   io.write(typeit) -- print the code to the terminal
   tex.sprint(typeit) -- write a character to a TeX file
   previous=droid -- store an actual font family to avoid repetion 
end
end
\end{luacode*}
\def\maltig#1{\toks0{#1}% Save parameter to be load by Lua.
   \begingroup% Begin of font manipulation.
   \directlua{changeme()}% Processing string at a Lua level.
   \endgroup% End of font manipulation.
   }% End of \maltig command.

\begin{document}
\section*{Section about Tigrinya}
Text before it. \maltig{0 123 abc 456 789 እንሆ ኸኣ በታ መዓልቲ እቲኣ ኽልተ ኻባታቶም ካብ የሩሳሌም ስሳ እስታድዮስ ዝምርሓቓ ኤማሁስ ናብ እትብሃል ዓዲ ይኸዱ ነበሩ።} Text after it.
\end{document}
```

[image: An example of the improved source code]

---

### Version 1 (old; wrapping every single character)

[Droid font family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_fonts) is licensed under Apache license [[download](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/data/fonts)]. Before I realised that, I had downloaded and unzipped the [Code2000](http://www.fonts2u.com/download/code2000.font) font into my working directory.

This is an example with LuaTeX as a TeX engine and string manipulation of the wrapped block of text. In general, this chunk of code could be simplified via a callback (there would be no more need for tagging foreign parts) and switching between fonts when there is a need for it instead of grouping every single character (that would assure creation of ligatures and kerning pairs).

I enclose the code (we run `lualatex mal-droid.tex`) and a preview of the PDF file.

```
% lualatex mal-droid.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luatextra}

% http://www.fonts2u.com/download/code2000.font
\newfontfamily{\ethiopicfont}[Scale=1,Color=red,ExternalLocation=./]{Code2000.TTF}
\begin{luacode*}
function changeme()
text=tex.toks[0]
for i=1,unicode.utf8.len(text) do
   char=unicode.utf8.sub(text,i,i)
   if char<="9" then tex.sprint("{\\setmainfont[Color=green]{Latin Modern Roman}{}"..char.."}") else tex.sprint(char) end
end
end
\end{luacode*}
\def\maltig#1{\toks0{#1}{\ethiopicfont\directlua{changeme()}}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Section about Tigrinya}
Text before it. \maltig{0 123 456 789 እንሆ ኸኣ በታ መዓልቲ እቲኣ ኽልተ ኻባታቶም ካብ የሩሳሌም ስሳ እስታድዮስ ዝምርሓቓ ኤማሁስ ናብ እትብሃል ዓዲ ይኸዱ ነበሩ።} Text after it.
\end{document}
```

[image: an example]

Comment: Droid is not specificaly licendesd you can get it under a free license, see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_fonts

Comment: Issuing `\setmainfont` *before* each character is likely to be very inefficient, and is also wrong way to do it since every character will be set in a different font and kerning or any other interaction between the characters at the font level will be lost.