# Cannot compile old luatex code

Tags: luatex

I can't compile the answer given here:

[In LuaTex is it possible to change font/language according to the script/glyphs used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21625/in-luatex-is-it-possible-to-change-font-language-according-to-the-script-glyphs)

Is it because it's old? My compiler says that `\luatexdirectlua` is undefined.

PS. With `\directlua` the error is:

```
! LuaTeX error luatexinterchartoks.lua:1: unexpected symbol near '%' stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'dofile'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk. l.35 \directlua{dofile('luatexinterchartoks.lua')}
```

PS II. deleted ll. 1 and 2, now the error is:

```
! LuaTeX error ...ocal/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109:

Module luatexbase Error: Attempt to use callback.register() directly
(luatexbase)             on input line 35

stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        ...ocal/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109: in function 'm
odule_error'
        ...ocal/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:116: in function 'l
uatexbase_error'
        ...ocal/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:291: in function 'r
egister'
        luatexinterchartoks.lua:64: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'dofile'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.35 \directlua{dofile('luatexinterchartoks.lua')}
```

Comment: as documented in latex news, you should use `\directlua` (the original name) the latex setup no longer renames luatex commands with the luatex prefix

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I did suspect and try that, but it still wouldn't compile.

Comment: if you give no hints about the error that you got, then no hints on how the error may be fixed.

Comment: delete the line `% luatexinterchartoks.lua` that is a title for the website but not legal lua

Comment: that's the issue Ulrike put in a comment replace the callback register line at the end of the lua by `luatexbase.add_to_callback ('token_filter', do_intertoks,"xetex chartoks emulation")` then it loads without error (but doesn't work, at least in my development build of luatex, looking....)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, it works with 0.80.0, thanks for the help!

Comment: as warned elsewhere luatex 0.8x breaks most things including this: the token_filter callback used there is gone with no documented replacement, I'm about to ask on the luatex list if that was intended.....

Comment: Note that the code will not work at all in luatex 0.89 as the `token_filter` callback has been removed with no replacement http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2016-February/005651.html

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the code will not work at all in luatex 0.89 as the `token_filter` callback which was available in some beta releases of luatex has been removed with no replacement http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2016-February/005651.html