# How to use Chinese with lualatex?

Tags: luatex, cjk

Searching through tex.stackexchange.com, I've come to understand that `xetex` is currently the preferred engine for documents that include Chinese characters. In `xetex`, one simply uses the `xeCJK` or `ctex` packages and start including the characters in the body of the document. But it appears these two packages don't work with `luatex`.

So is it possible to include Chinese characters in a document using `luatex`? I cannot find a single example of this.

Comment: You can include Chinese characters, but for a full fledged support of Chinese, I don't think there are good tools with LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 19):

Just use `luatexja`. The Chinese TeX community decide not to develop a new package but use `luatexja`, because the tools designed for Chinese and Japanese usually work the same.

The developer version of our `ctex` package will provide a Chinese customized interface for `luatexja`. Now you can use `luatexja` directly.

Here is an example:

[image]

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainjfont{FandolSong}
\begin{document}

在 Lua\TeX{} 中正常地使用中文。获得自动的\textbf{字体选择}，标点“压缩”，以及正确的断行处理等特性。

\end{document}
```

**Note:** `fontspec` alone is insufficient. You need proper line breaking, punctuation kerning and font switching features provided by `luatexja`.

Comment: Six and a half years later, is this still the proper way? I’m considering to switch from xelatex (I’m very happy with xecjk) to lualatex and I’m not sure where to start.

Comment: Is `luatexja` "neutral" to the non-CJK part?  I ask this question because I want to use Japanese a little bit within my otherwise English documents.

Comment: luatexja is not as good as xeCJK.

Comment: `\textit` doesn't seem to work in this context, are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 3):

very basic use would be

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{MS PGothic}
\begin{document}
我希望這是，翻譯是由谷歌提供的中國文字。
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe, for short Chinese inserts, `\newfontfamily` is better.

Comment: Thanks. I understand there is a `setCJKmainfont` in xeCJK. Does this command exist in lualatex? I'd like to use separate fonts for English and Chinese if possible.

Comment: I understand I can use `\newfontfamily` but that would mean I have to explicitly indicate when to switch to a Chinese font. With `setCJKmainfont` it switches automatically.

Comment: @ana sorry I don't know too much about available CJK packages, I just wanted to demonstrate that basic typesetting of text was easy enough with fontspec package an luatex.

Comment: @ana `xeCJK` uses various XeTeX mechanisms with direct correspondence in LuaTeX, and therefore you cannot really have proper CJK typesetting with LuaTeX at this time.  See [Is there a LuaTeX analogue to XeTeXinterchartoks?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21604)

Comment: It won't work if you type more characters. The line break algorithm designed for western languages doesn't work for East Asian languages.