# LuaLaTeX - Pinyin over rare Chinese characters

Tags: math-mode, fonts, characters, cjk, pinyin

I know that using the `xpinyin` package can solve this, but I need to use Lualatex, which is not supported.

At first I used the following code:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\zhuyin[2]{$\overset{\textrm{#1}}{#2}$}

\begin{document}
\zhuyin{tiān}{天}
\end{document}
```

For general Chinese characters, it works very well.

But now I have some rare characters that need to be annotated, they are in the Unicode Extension B area, which means that the normal font does not include them (I've tried fonts like Source Han Sans): (U+2724D), (U+27246). On my system, it seems that only simsunb.ttf can display them. I'm having trouble changing the font in mathematical mode. I tried the following code and it failed:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\zhuyin[2]{$\overset{\textrm{#1}}{#2}$}
\newfontfamily{\zyextb}{simsunb.ttf}[NFSSFamily=simsunb]
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathzy}{TU}{simsunb}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
%I also tried \zhuyin{jí}{\zyextb }
\zhuyin{jí}{\mathzy }
\end{document}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224734/119) suggests that you can use `luatexja` (developed for Japanese + LuaTeX) for Chinese typesetting too. `luatexja` (according to the manual) has an add-on `luatexja-ruby` package for typesetting pronunciation annotations. Maybe you can look into that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `luatexja-ruby` package.

```tex
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{luatexja-ruby}
\newcommand\zhuyin[3][]{\ltjruby[{#1}]{#3}{#2}}
\newCJKfontfamily{\esimsun}{simsun.ttc}[NFSSFamily=esimsun,
  AlternateFont=
    {
      {"20000->"2FA1D}{simsunb.ttf}, 
%      {"30000->"323AF}{simsung.ttf}
    }]

\begin{document}

\zhuyin{tiān}{天}
\zhuyin{jí}{\esimsun }

{\esimsun\zhuyin{tiān|jí}{天|}}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

CJK characters are **JAchar**, and their fonts are different from **ALchar**'s. `\newfontfamily` is using to set ALChar's font.

You can use `AlternateFont` key to set alternate fonts, so that this font command can switch to another font automatically.